# How to split NSArray into NSDictationary by param

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of objects, each object have param. For example I have an array

```
obj0 {age: 18; name: Jack; class: 1a}
obj1 {age: 18; name: Jim; class: 1b}
obj2 {age: 19; name: John; class: 1b}
obj3 {age: 20; name: JB; class: 1c}
```

I need  to split my array into `NSDictionary` by param. If I take param age, it will split into `NSDictionary`:

```
Array0:  obj0 {age: 18; name: Jack; class: 1a}
         obj1 {age: 18; name: Jim; class: 1b}
Key: 18

Array1:  obj2 {age: 19; name: John; class: 1b}
Key: 19

Array2:  obj3 {age: 20; name: JB; class: 1c}
Key20
```

How can I realize it?

Comment: Shocking as it may seem, you write software to do this.  Start by creating a new mutable dictionary and then looping through your array to insert entries into it.  Show us some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And actual Objective-C code based on Cyrille's answer:

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for(Object *e in allObjects)
{
    NSMutableArray *mutArrForAge = [result objectForKey:e.age];
    if(mutArrForAge == nil)
    {
        mutArrForAge = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [result setObject:mutArrForAge forKey:e.age];
    }
    [mutArrForAge addObject:e];
}
```

Voilá * 2

Comment: -1 for giving a code answer to a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: We got a guy with 663 rep, and some well upvoted answers. The question is well written, might it be without code. I can accept your downvote, but c'mon. It's not like we are taking an exam here.

Comment: It's not like the guy demonstrated any effort.

Comment: Not with code, no. But the question is still well written. I know that you sometimes get totally stunned and really ain't got a clue of how to solve the most trivial problems. Sure, the pseudo code should be "enough" for him to get on the right track, but still. I am not judging anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo code :

```
result = new mutable dictionary
for each (object in array)
   age = object[@"age"]
   if (result[age] does not exist)
      result[age] = new mutable array
   append object to result[age]
```

Voilà.